# Get access to Spring Model variable from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How I can get access to variable (which was added as attribute to Model in my controller) in JavaScript and how I can work with properties of it?

My model:

```
public class Category {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAllCategories(Model model) {
    List <Category> categories = categoryService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("categories", categories);
    return "index";
}
```

On my web page I need to show all categories (no problem, using Thymeleaf th:each="category : `${categories}"`) and have ability add new category to categories variable and set its properties (id, name, recipes for example).
So, how I can get access to variable 'categories' in JavaScript, and how I can add new element and set properties in `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call to this method

```
// using jquery
 $.ajax({
    url:'/',
    success:function(response){
       // get the return pf the method here
       // can be assigned to any variable
    }
```

java method change

```
 @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAllCategories(Model model) {
     //rest of code
    return (the value which which you want to assign to model property);
}
```

[**Explore more about ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an API. [Rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) for example.
The idea is to create methods callable by javascript(via [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) for example), and do the operations you need to do in java.

Here you have some pseudocode:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/addCategory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public boolean AddCategory(Model model) {
  //Do your logic to add category

  if (/*everything went good*/) return true;
  else return fale;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use `Model`?, when you can directly access the object as `JSON`:

**JS Snippet using Angular:**

```
$http.get('/app/get').then(function(response) {
        $scope.categoryList = response.data;
 }, function(response) {
});
```

**JS Snippet using Jquery:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/app/get",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
        var categoryList = response.data;
        console.log(categoryList);
      }
});
```

**Java Snippet:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping(path = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List <Category> showAllCategories() {
    return categoryService.findAll();
 }
}
```